# I am beginner here.Could any one please suggest telescope on AliExpress

Tags: telescope

I am beginner and eager to buy telescope for viewing planets and deep sky objects. I have gone though several posts here and found that only magnification is not so important but along magnification image should be crisp and sharp. So that one can be amazed. 
Only source of purchasing telescope i have is aliexpress, please could any one be kind enough for me to find a good telescope there.price range MAX USD300.

Comment: Purchase recommendations tend to end up with no best answer, and so are not a good fit for the site. Its like asking for the "best car". No one size fits all. As a beginner, start with the naked eye (go out tonight and watch the meteors! no telescope required), then binoculars/monoculars. When you are ready to buy a telescope you will know what you want.

Comment: Viewing planets and deep sky objects on a $300 telescope is likely going to be unsatisfying. Try a [virtual telescope](https://www.virtualtelescope.eu/) for free and save up a lot more money over the years, or simply rely on the images from multi-million dollar telescopes and billion dollar space probes - a $300 telescope won't get images like you can find with a search engine.

Comment: @Muhammad Waqar which one did you end up buying can you give any feedback >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AliExpress advertise Celestron astronomical telescopes. Celestron is a reputable manufacturer, and these scopes should be good quality, providing that they are **genuine** Celestron scopes and not Chinese rip-offs. Unfortunately, most of the none-computerised scopes have equatorial mounts, which are fiddly for beginners to use. An alt-azimuth mount will be easier to handle. Get the biggest aperture that you can afford, and check reviews on YouTube specifically for scopes sourced through AliExpress. Think twice before you sacrifice aperture for computerised control. You already know to ignore magnification claims.

This is about the best advice that I can provide, given the nature of your post.